# Big array gives segmentation error in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am really new to C, so I am sorry if this is a absolute beginner question, but I am getting a segmentation error when I am building large array, relevant bits of what I am doing is:

```
unsigned long long ust_limit;
unsigned long long arr_size;

/* ust_limit gets value around here ... */

arr_size = ((ust_limit + 1) / 2) - 1;
unsigned long long numbs[(int)arr_size];
```

This works for some values of ust_limit, but when it gets above approximately 4.000.000 a segmentation fault occurs. What I want is to detect a possible segfault and fail gracefully. How can I know which values would cause a segmentation fault. And, is this something platform dependant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely getting a stack overflow, since you are creating a very large array on the stack. To avoid this, allocate the memory dynamically:

```
unsigned long long *numbs = malloc(arr_size * sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

Later, when you are finished with the array, free it again:

```
free(numbs);
```

Comment: Can I use numbs like how would I use an array after doing this? For example, can I access indexes?

Comment: Yes, you can use it the same way. For example indexing works the same on a pointer to some memory as it works on an array.

Answer (score 1):

You array stores on stack frame, which has a limit to its size, use `malloc` instead.

```
unsigned long long *numbs = malloc(arr_size * sizeof(long long));
// don't forget to free after use
free(numbs)
```

Comment: I am not sure about how to do that, I am really beginner at this, an example maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You're consuming too much stack. The limit is platform dependent.

The exact limit depends on the OS. These limits can be changed to some extent on some operating systems .

For large amounts of memory, you should be using the head with `malloc` and/or `calloc` (and `free`).

Answer (score 1):

`numbs` is a Variable Length Array (VLA).

VLAs can be created only in block scope (i.e., inside a function).  They're allocated like any other local variable, typically on the stack.

Unfortunately, the language doesn't provide a way of detecting or handling allocation failures for local variables.  If you allocate too much memory, your program will crash *if you're lucky*.

Large objects whose size isn't known at compile time should be allocated via `malloc()` (which means you need to keep track of the allocation and release them with `free()`).

Incidentally, there's no need to cast `arr_size` to `int`.  And both `ust_limit` and `arr_size` should be of type `size_t` (defined in `<stddef.h>`).

Example:

```
unsigned long long numbs = malloc(arr_size * sizeof *numbs);
/* And later, when you're done with it */
free(numbs);
```